# How to display a widget above a tab in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, tabs

I have a bottom tab bar.

When some conditions are met, I need to display a widget abode a given tab as follows:

[image]

For simplicity, I display a `Text("ALERT")` here, but in the real app it'll be a tapable widget.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution in two steps:

1. Use a `Column` and insert the widget first, and the tabbar last: but this makes your bottom app appears taller than what one wants. This gives you:

[image]

2. Add `extendBody:true` which makes the area above the actual TabBar transparent so that removes the unwanted area:

[image]

```dart
Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  bottomNavigationBar: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Chip(
        label: Text("Draft pending"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      bottomTabBar,
    ]
  )
  // blah blah
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap whatever widget you have (in your case Text widget for example) with a GestureDetector widget like this:

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            // What happens with the tap
          });
        },
      ),
```